# node.js & Express / body parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I write server side application with `express` & `node.js.`

I have the next:

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});
```

Everything works good, but:

1. As I understand, this method was deprecated.
2. The next method doesn't work well. It writes some random chars instead of writing the correct chars:

   ```
   app.post('/randomWrite', function (req, res) {
   var fileName = req.body.name;
   var contentLength = parseInt(req.files.file._writeStream.bytesWritten);
   var start = parseInt(req.body.chunk) * 102400;
   var buffer = new Buffer(parseInt(req.files.file._writeStream.bytesWritten));
   fs.open(req.files.file.path, 'r', function (status, fd) {
       if (fd == null) {
           console.log("Can't open the file with the fd");
           return;
       }
       fileNameLocation = "./" + fileName;
       fs.open(fileNameLocation, 'w+', function (err, fd1) {
           fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, contentLength, start, function (err, bytesRead, buffer1) {
               if (err)
                   console.log("ERROR: " + err);
               fs.write(fd1, buffer1, 0, contentLength, start, function (err, bytesWrite, buffer) {
                   if (req.body.chunk == req.body.chunks - 1) {
                       fs.close(fd, function (err) {
                       })
                       fs.close(fd1, function (err) {
                       })
                       FileServer.prototype.returnResCodeWithId(res, 200, id);
                   } else {
                       fs.close(fd, function (err) {

                       })
                       fs.close(fd1, function (err) {

                       })
                       FileServer.prototype.returnResCode(res, 200);
                   }
               })
           })
       })
   })
   ```

Instead of writing in the correct offset, it seems that something get wrong and some text from the middleware (bodyParser) is written.

How can i change the express.bodyParser()? It will fix my problem with the writing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware.

You can install it with

```
npm install body-parser
```

and include it with Express using

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser());
```

If you want file uploads too, then have a look at [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Thanks, bit it still write some random chars. there is a problem with the `fs.write` and `fs.read` of this method?